# Using tslint to enforce immutability

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tslint

As a novice React developer, I just became aware that I have been inadvertently mutating the state and props directly.

There are tons of examples of:

```
const {variable} = this.props;
variable[index] = value;
// do something local with var - not realizing that variable is changed
```

There are hundreds of instances in my codebase of this.

Is there a tslint rule or a way that I can find each instance where I've mutated props or state which should be readonly.

I know that there's a tslint rule out there along the lines of

`TS2540: Cannot assign to ‘url’ because it is a constant or a read-only property.`

but I have no clue how to turn it on. From my understanding, in React Typescript, the props and state are wrapped in Readonly<> which should trigger this error any time I attempt to mutate the props or state.

Comment: no, you/tslint can't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare them as `readonly` when you create the interfaces and use `ReadonlyArray` for arrays, for your props and state eg:

```
interface ButtonProps {
  readonly onChange: (event: ChangeEvent) => void;
  readonly classes: ReadonlyArray<string>;
}

class Button extends React.Component<ButtonProps> { ... }
```

That way you should get the check everywhere, as long as all members are `readonly`, and it is the typescript compiler that will error, not tslint.

One thing you can do is use rules from [tslint-immutable](https://github.com/jonaskello/tslint-immutable#readme) to ensure you don't miss out any `readonly` on interfaces and arrays